# How to find element using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a list of elements:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li style="display: none"></li>
    <li style="display: none"></li>
    <li style="display: none"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to take only elements without this `style="display: none"`.

Any suggestions how to distinguish between those with `style="display: none"` and those without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> lis = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul li:not([style*='display: none'])"));
```

List without display : none element...

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to get all `<li>` elements that don't have `style="display: none"` in their HTML code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('li:not([style="display: none"])'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing ,

```
String s = webelement.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

Now use the String s to parse the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cssSelector` with `:not`

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li:not([style='display: none']"));
```

This will get all `<li>` tags that doesn't have `style='display: none'`